# Select2, fire an event when "no results found" using ajax

Tags: ajax, events, jquery-select2

I am using multiple instances of select2 with data dependency. I am trying to disable depending Select2 element if there is no results or JSON is empty (using multi Select2 with Ajax).

For an example, I have dependency on selected value in "products". If product selection has available sub categories, I need to enable "sub Category select2" and load dependent sub-categories. But if selected product does **not** have sub categories I should keep my "sub Category select2" disabled. So I need solution to trigger an event when there is no data in JSON.   How do I trigger event if there is no match / data?

Thank you all for helping, but I could not find anything in Select2 documentation so far. I might be missing something very obvious.

Here is an dummy example of what I am trying to do.Something like "NoMatchesFound"

```
$("#sub-category").select2({
  ajax: {
    ***** and so on***, but will return no results from CMS
   } 
  NoMatchesFound: function(data) {
        // if no matches disable this.select2
        // if no matches do something here 
  }
```

});

Comment: What about triggering events inside option ```processResults``` ? There you can check results length and trigger custom events (or directly disable dependent dropdowns)

Comment: Thank you for comment Dario, I already tried that but what is happening is that I have to click on select2 container in order to see message. I need to disable container if data do not match by default. So in general cannot trigger ajax initial data to display the moment after select2 is created / initiated.